# Getting the last part of elements when splitting a string

Tags: c#, split

Here's what I'm trying to workout split function.

The `com` is a string passed from a textbox, and it removes the first piece from the text.

The text in the textbox is being pass as this `".fedex TYU-123 Time to pick up package"`

Then, when `gms` is part of the first piece of the `strip[]` array.

```
string format = com.Remove(0,1);
string[] strip = format.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (strip[0] == "gsm")
{
    string carrier = strip[0];
    string trackid = strip[1];
    string message = strip[2];
}
```

`strip[2]` only contains `"Time"`. I wanted to return the last part as this: `"Time to pick up package"`.

Keep in mind also, since the message will be different at times as well, so I don't want a specific string search.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want all words starting with the third, use `string.Join(" ", strip.Skip(2))`:

```
string[] strip = format.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (strip[0] == "gsm")
{
    string carrier = strip[0];
    string trackid = strip[1];
    string message = string.Join(" ", strip.Skip(2)); //Time to pick up package
}
```

Comment: That one is the best method since I don't want to change the string[] strip function. Works Great! :D Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you only want to split the first three elements.

[`Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) has an overload that lets you tell it how many items to return:

```
format.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string.Split(char[], int32) method for this, in which you can give a max. number of splitted strings to return.

So:

```
format.Split(new[] {' '}, 3);
```

would do the trick.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

Comment: I think your either your answer should be different or you have to vote the answer that you were thinking and in the meanwhile somebody already provided that. That will reduce the unnecessary duplicacy in the post